# Getting OpenIDConnect provider's HTTPS certificate with Gitlab

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, openid-connect

I am facing an issue while accessing AWS resources with the OIDC provider from GitLab CICD.

- OIDC configured successfully.

I am creating it with below terraform code,

```
data "tls_certificate" "gitlab" {
  url = var.mygitlab
}

resource "aws_iam_openid_connect_provider" "gitlab" {
  url             = var.mygitlab
  client_id_list  = [var.mygitlab_aud_value]
  thumbprint_list = [data.tls_certificate.gitlab.certificates.0.sha1_fingerprint]
}
```

when I am creating it via aws console manual it is working fine. so please guide how we can create proper with terraform.

[image: oidc issue]

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. You have a certificate thumbprint mismatch. When creating the OIDC provider in AWS, did you verify the provider? (by viewing the "verify provider information" page in the console). See [the aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc_verify-thumbprint.html) for more info

Comment: No i dint but let me check. I have created OIDC with terraform.

Comment: I'm guessing you may have just added the wrong cert fingerprint. What fingerprint value did you use and where did you get it from? And are you using a self-hosted instance or GitLab.com?

Comment: I am using terraform code to generate fingerprint for OIDC.                                    data "tls_certificate" "gitlab" {
  url = var.mygitlab
}

resource "aws_iam_openid_connect_provider" "gitlab" {
  url             = var.mygitlab
  client_id_list  = [var.mygitlab_aud_value]
  thumbprint_list = [data.tls_certificate.gitlab.certificates.0.sha1_fingerprint]
}

Comment: I have generate manual fingerprint in aws console and pass as variable in terraform code and it is resolved.

Comment: Is it some how possible to do this with GitLab self hosted and private instance (not available via internet)?

Answer (score 0):

I have generate manual fingerprint in aws console and pass as variable in terraform code and it is resolved.

[image: solutions i applied]

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the AWS [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc_verify-thumbprint.html), you have to take the field `jwks_uri` from: https://gitlab.com/.well-known/openid-configuration to fill the TLS certificate url:

```
data "tls_certificate" "gitlab" {
  url = "${var.gitlab_url}/oauth/discovery/keys"
}

resource "aws_iam_openid_connect_provider" "gitlab" {
  url             = "${var.gitlab_url}"
  client_id_list  = [var.gitlab_aud_value]
  thumbprint_list = [data.tls_certificate.gitlab.certificates.0.sha1_fingerprint]
}
```

With variables:

```
variable "gitlab_url" {
  type        = string
  default     = "https://gitlab.com"
  description = "GitLab URL"
}

variable "gitlab_aud_value" {
  type        = string
  default     = "https://gitlab.com"
  description = "GitLab Aud"
}
```